# Migrating SQLite data from Rails 2 to 3

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, copy, migrate

I'm in the process of migrating the data from a Rails 2 application, to a new Rails 3 application. The new database shares a number of columns with the old database, and I'm looking to copy some of the data over from the old database to the new one.

How should I go about this?

Comment: Are you talking about data or structure?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a large amount of data what I'd do is dump the data you want into a file, then either in a separate rake task or the seeds.rb file do something like:

```
sql = **read in your file***
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```